# Endless Syntax Errors for sqlite in terminal

Tags: python, sqlite, terminal, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to lean sqlite3 and create databases, but I'm having trouble getting started. I go to the Terminal and start things off by typing sqlite3. I get the following prompt:

```
sqlite>
```

I installed sqlAcademy and am trying to work through the tutorial, but with examples like:

```
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> sqlalchemy.__version__ 
0.7.0
```

They appear to be typing in the Terminal, but my code shows an error:

```
sqlite> import sqlalchemy;
Error: near "import": syntax error
```

Is there a wrapper I should be using in Terminal so I can type in Python? Do I need to individually write, compile, and run all of the example or is there an easier way?

I know this sounds vague, but I think I'm doing something very obvious wrong. Just too new to know what it is.

Comment: Did you notice the difference between the tutorial prompt (`>>>`) and the SQLite prompt (`sqlite>`)?  What do you think that difference means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're running in sqlite terminal. The sample code should be run from python's terminal.

Comment: Just to expand for simplicity: In the ***SQLite*** terminal you can write and execute SQL - In the ***Python*** terminal you can write and execute Python, and you can use the SQLAlchemy library to interact with your SQLite Databases in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 1):

To further expand on Demian's answer:

In the terminal type:

```
$ python
```

you will get (or similar depending on which version of python you have installed)

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

From there you can enter your `import sqlalchemy`

Alternatively you can create a python script file (*.py) and put your code in it. Then run run the code by changing to the directory that your files are in, and entering

```
python filename.py
```

Hope that helps.